# Block user without pem with SSH

Tags: ssh, sshd

I have Amazon Linux server and just realize that I can access my server without pem.

In my server's **/etc/ssh/sshd**, **"PasswordAuthentication no"** and **"ChallengeResponseAuthentication no"**.

But when I try to connect without any dummy key:

```bsh
$ ssh -i <MY_SERVER_IP> a <user>@<MY_SERVER_IP>
```

It just gives me warning but allow to access.

```bsh
Warning: Identity file a not accessible: No such file or directory.
Last login: Mon Jul  8 05:35:23 2019 from 106.240.50.74
```

I don't know why it is allowed, how should I block access without pem key?

Comment: so does it let you in or you just see an error message? what does `ssh -vvv` to that server tell you?

Comment: @Bart There's no error message, just warning message and allow to access my server. Here's the output with -v option: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ChhVQdzjWG6tCGSe_W2AY0KZ4_LGDaaS/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have a SSH private key file named `<MY_SERVER_IP>`, the SSH client falls back to using a default key file:

```
debug1: identity file /Users/han/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
...
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: ...
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <MY_SERVER_IP> ([...]:22).
```

And it looks like the corresponding public key has been added into `~<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys` on `<MY_SERVER_IP>`, so the key authentication succeeds.